# Matching data from two different tables in SQL

Tags: sql, sql-server

Can someone help me with matching data from two different tables please?

1. I have specific select condition for the table "A" with the list of account numbers. F.E:

```
SELECT [Document Number]
     ,[Account Number]
 FROM [dbo].[A]
 where [Account Number] in ('1111','2222','3333')
```

2. I got values for [Document Number] column
3. I have to find these [Document Number] values from Table "B".
   I know that i could find them using

```
SELECT [Document Number]
      ,[Account Number]
  FROM [dbo].[B]
where [Document Number] in ('Data from table "A"')
```

but it is enormous amount of data there.

Can someone help me with matching these two tables using JOINs for example?

Comment: Have a look at `EXISTS`.

Answer (score 0):

You may write your query using the following join:

```sql
SELECT b.[Document Number], b.[Account Number]
FROM [dbo].[B] b
INNER JOIN [dbo].[A] a
    ON a.[Document Number] = b.[Document Number]
WHERE a.[Account Number] IN ('1111', '2222', '3333');
```